# Same p12 certificate, different trust chain on different machines, why?

Tags: certificate

I have a p12 file. This was generated from a DigiCert p7b.

When I import this into my personal store on one machine (windows server, using certificates mmc) it shows me one chain when I view the path.

Using the same file, I import into my personal store on a different machine (also windows, using certs mmc). On this one I see a different path (and in this case it has an expired hop)

Specifically, two hops above my cert the divergence occurs.

Why does this happen? Is there anything I can do to influence that chain (remember its the same p12 that is creating different paths)?

I should also say, I am no expert in this area. I'm a developer that muddles through these security issues when needed.

Comment: Could you explore this p12 file? Does it have certificates of issuing CAs? You can use [XCA](http://sourceforge.net/projects/xca/) to do this. I assume that somewhere in certification chain is a certificate that was cross-certified. Also on on of your machines you probably have manually imported different chain. It would be good to test importing this p12 on fresh windows installations. I bet that the certificate chain will be the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Closing this out. 
I'm still a little foggy on why things were working the way they did but some things made sense.
It seems the .p12 was created from a p7b that included some of the intermediate certs. One of the included intermediates was the bad one. This explains why the chain was bad on one machine.

Still not sure how I was able to see a good chain on different machine but I understand why I saw the bad one. It seems the good chain was the fluke and the bad chain should have been expected (I originally assumed the opposite).

I created a new .p12 without the intermediates. Cleaned up all the bad intermediates that were previously imported from the first .p12 in both service user and local machine stores. All seems to be working as expected now with same valid chain on all machines.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. Two different windows 2008 r2 servers, same certificate. After standard OS patching one of the servers was sending only the first layer of certificate trust chain (number 0), so the openssl client was failing with the message:
verify error:num=21:unable to verify the first certificate

No idea what was the root cause. I tried to

- reassign certificate in IIS
- reimport certificate
- restart IIS

with no success. What finally helped to fix the issue was the server reboot...